react native @react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js error
`:ReactNative:Unexpected empty result of running '[node, C:\Users\rahim\OneDrive\Masa├╝st├╝\mobil\aiAppTest\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]' command.
:ReactNative:Running '[node, C:\Users\rahim\OneDrive\Masa├╝st├╝\mobil\aiAppTest\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]' command failed.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Where:
Script 'C:\Users\rahim\OneDrive\Masa³st³\mobil\aiAppTest\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 391

What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.



node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1147  throw err;  ^Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\rahim\OneDrive\Masa├â┬╝st├â┬╝\mobil\aiAppTest\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js'    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1144:15)    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:27)    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12)    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',  requireStack: []}Node.js v20.11.1


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BU¦LD FAILED in 2s
Error: C:\Users\rahim\OneDrive\Masaüstü\mobil\aiAppTest\android\gradlew.bat exited with non-zero code: 1
Error: C:\Users\rahim\OneDrive\Masaüstü\mobil\aiAppTest\android\gradlew.bat exited with non-zero code: 1
at ChildProcess.completionListener (C:\Users\rahim\OneDrive\Masaüstü\mobil\aiAppTest\node_modules@expo\spawn-async\build\spawnAsync.js:52:23)
at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:633:26)
at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:518:28)
at cp.emit (C:\Users\rahim\OneDrive\Masaüstü\mobil\aiAppTest\node_modules@expo\spawn-async\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:34:29)
at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1105:16)
at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:305:5)
...
at Object.spawnAsync [as default] (C:\Users\rahim\OneDrive\Masaüstü\mobil\aiAppTest\node_modules@expo\spawn-async\build\spawnAsync.js:17:21)
at spawnGradleAsync (C:\Users\rahim\OneDrive\Masaüstü\mobil\aiAppTest\node_modules@expo\cli\build\src\start\platforms\android\gradle.js:72:46)
at Object.assembleAsync (C:\Users\rahim\OneDrive\Masaüstü\mobil\aiAppTest\node_modules@expo\cli\build\src\start\platforms\android\gradle.js:52:18)
at runAndroidAsync (C:\Users\rahim\OneDrive\Masaüstü\mobil\aiAppTest\node_modules@expo\cli\build\src\run\android\runAndroidAsync.js:36:24)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)`
expo run:android
I get this error while running the code, how can I solve it?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
